# Why does Kaspersky blocks a website saying untrusted root center

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority, antivirus

Why does Kaspersky antivirus blocks the website saying that it has untrusted root center when the root CA is Kasperksy itself and also the certificate status seems to be "OK".
Figure-1 shows the blocked website and Figure-2 shows the root CA as Kaspersky.

**Figure-1**

[image: Figure1]

**Figure-2**

[image: Figure2]

Comment: Of course it shows Kaspersky as the Root CA, because you allow Kaspersky as SSL proxy (giving it the ability to see everything you enter on HTTPS sites). For your browser, the certificate it sees is Kaspersky's, but Kaspersky sees the real Root CA, and it is likely not in its storage of trusted Root CA's

Comment: @MechMK1 Thanks for explaining the concept. It was really helpful.

Comment: This inspired an interesting question. https://security.stackexchange.com/q/230511/70406